# Thymeleaf does not display data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, thymeleaf

I'm a beginner to `Spring` framework and `Thymeleaf`. I write a code which will display data from database on the website. I integrate my code with `MySQL` database. Somehow, when i view at the `localhost:8080`, the data does not display on the site at all.

**The Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private TicketService ticketService;

@Autowired
public void setTicketService(TicketService ticketService){
    this.ticketService = ticketService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("ticket", ticketService.listAllTickets());

    return "index";

}
}
```

**The Dao:**

```
 public interface TicketRepository extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer> {
 }
```

**The Model**

```
 public class Ticket {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String ticket_station;
private String ticket_text;
private int ticket_created_at;
private String ticket_issuer;

public String getTicket_station() {
    return ticket_station;
}

public void setTicket_station(String ticket_station) {
    this.ticket_station = ticket_station;
}

public String getTicket_text() {
    return ticket_text;
}

public void setTicket_text(String ticket_text) {
    this.ticket_text = ticket_text;
}

public int getTicket_created_at() {
    return ticket_created_at;
}

public void setTicket_created_at(int ticket_created_at) {
    this.ticket_created_at = ticket_created_at;
}

public String getTicket_issuer() {
    return ticket_issuer;
}

public void setTicket_issuer(String ticket_issuer) {
    this.ticket_issuer = ticket_issuer;
}

}
```

**The Service:**

```
public interface TicketService {
Iterable<Ticket> listAllTickets();

}
```

**The ServiceImpl:**

```
 @Service
 public class TicketServiceImpl implements TicketService {
private TicketRepository ticketrepository;

@Autowired
public void setProductRepository(TicketRepository ticketRepository) {
    this.ticketrepository = ticketRepository;
}

@Override
public Iterable<Ticket> listAllTickets() {
    return ticketrepository.findAll();
}
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
    <title>Ticket</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<style>
 table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 1px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
            <div>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Ticket Station</th>
                        <th>Ticket Text</th>
                        <th>Created at </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr th:each="ticket : ${ticket}">
                        <td th:text="${ticket.ticket_station}">Text ...</td>
                        <td th:text="${ticket.ticket_text}">Text ...</td>
                        <td th:text="${ticket.ticket_created_at}">Text ... 
   </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

**The Application properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dol
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Schema:**

```
   CREATE DATABASE dol;
   CREATE TABLE `dol`.`ticket` (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ticket_text VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     ticket_created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
     ticket_station VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id));

   INSERT INTO `dol`.`ticket` ( `ticket_text`, `ticket_station`, 
   `ticket_created_at`) VALUES ( 'wow', 'London', '2018-01-13 15:59:26');
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.pstw</groupId>
<artifactId>Portal</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Portal</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Maybe you should view `localhost:8080/index` instead of `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: I've use localhost:8080 and it still work. But somehow at the table the data from database does not come out.(localhost:8080/index , I try it shows error whitelable error page).

Comment: @Wero Do you have thymeleaf in your classpath?

Comment: @SangamBelose I think I do not have classpath.

Comment: What build tool you are using? How are referring the spring jars..? Check whether you have thymeleaf jar in your dependencies

Comment: @SangamBelose I'm using NetBeans IDE. I think in my pom.xml have thymeleaf dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Thymeleaf can handle Iterable. Try passing a simple Arraylist in your Controller or Service.

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
ticket.setTicket....
List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>(ticket);
model.addAttribute("ticket", tickets);
```

If that works, change Iterable to List in your service and try again. Maybe it isn't a problem with your MySql data